# Cannot update TextBox DataTrigger on first letter

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I am trying to achieve something very simple but I am having a very small issue. I have a TextBox where users needs to enter the Type. The type should only be '1' or 'a'. What I came up with was to change the BorderBrush to red when the user has entered something other than these values.

This seems to work but in order to turn the color to red I need to enter two letters... So if I just press d, it will be gray, if I press dd it will then turn red. Is there a way to make it turn red on the first letter?

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SelectedShippingRate.Type, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="4" >
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedShippingRate.Type, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedShippingRate.Type, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Value="a">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Is Type the string or instance of class Type?

Comment: Type is the string

Comment: Does your view model implement INotifyPropertyChanged and setter of this property run   OnPropertyChanged()?

Comment: Personally, I'd use the KeyUp event, and do it via code.  I know it's not what you asked, but is that not an option?

Comment: To notify your data trigger about changing of value of Type propery, you should mplement INotifyPropertyChanged and setter of this property run OnPropertyChanged(), overwise  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" /> will never be applied via data trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses. It looks it was already working but the BorderBrush would always be blue because..... the textbox border is always blue(ish) when focused :D . So I just added a Border around it and added the trigger on the border instead.